# Can I create folders on user machine when they download files?

Tags: directory, download

Is there a way to allow user to download .png files with a certain folder structure? I.e. Main folder with 10 sub folders. Each sub folder contains multiple png files. The folder structure is very important as I want certain png files in one folder while some are in another one.

Comment: A website cannot just create folders (and put unexpected files in them) on a user's device. It's a **security issue** that could be exploited by some virus, hackers, etc. Your best option is to [create a ZIP file in JS](https://www.google.com/search?q=create+a+ZIP+file+in+JS) for the user to download. The ZIP file would (or should) have your required _"folder structure"_ in there with the PNG files.

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a .zip file for them with the folder structure that you want.